# Does PhpStorm support Console Prompts?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, webstorm, prompt

[image]I'm using PhpStorm for Node development and using the Prompt plugin to prompt the user for input.  My script works from a command prompt (Windows) but doesn't seem to accept input with PhpStorm.

Comment: How do you start the script in both? What do you get instead of the prompt? Consider a screenshot helpful in doubt.

Comment: Added a screenshot, thanks.  The error is not getting a prompt but in replying to it.

Comment: "testing" is what I typed in as a response.